# how to copy particular colum from one table to another table in oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle

employee table has emp_id, emp_name, city, mobile no, deptname, salary, joiningdate, relievingdate columns.

workingtime table has emp_id,working_hrs column.

How to add only working_hrs column along with the data?

I have tried following query.

```
INSERT INTO employee1 (working_hrs)
SELECT working_hrs  FROM workingtime
```

It is showing error

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "WORKING_HRS": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Hi, please format your code with code fences to make it more readable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you need to copy the data from the second table to a column in the first table? The first table doesn't have a column named `working_hrs` - that is what Oracle is complaining about. If you need to add a column to the table, you must add the column first - with an `alter table` statement; and then to populate the data, you would need an `update` statement, not an `insert`. I do hope you are a student rather than a professional in the field!

Answer (score 0):

As @mathguy mentioned in comment section, first you have to add a column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD your_column your_col_data_type;  --ADD working_hrs as DATE

--you can also add a DEFAULT value to your column
ADD your_column data_type default sysdate not null --sysdate the default value
```

After that, you should `update` your table/column:

```
UPDATE your_table e
SET e.your_column = 
 (SELECT working_hrs 
  FROM workingtime WHERE emp_id = e.emp_id)
WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT 1
  FROM workingtime WHERE emp_id = e.emp_id;
```

But if you're new in SQL, i think **you should make** a simple `select` statement:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.city, e.mobile_no, 
       e.deptname, e.salary, e.joiningdate, e.relievingdate,
       w.working_hrs
FROM employee e
JOIN workingtime w ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id;
```